# English number spelling

Tags: python, numbers, spelling

I'm solving exercise 17 from Euler's project, which is about number spelling (GB). I searched the web for number spelling rules, but didn't find anything suitable.

**Does anyone have a link to english number spelling rules (GB) (for example when to use/not to use 'and')?**

For example, how to spell correctly 342?

Here is my function I wrote, can you find any errors?

```
def compose(x):
    digits = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
    eleven_to_twenty = ['', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
    decades = ['', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']
    if x < 1000:
        if x < 100:
            if x < 20:
                if x <= 10:
                    return digits[x]
                else:
                    return eleven_to_twenty[x - 10]
            else:
                return decades[x / 10] + digits[x % 10]
        else:
            return digits[x / 100] + 'hundredand' + compose(x % 100)
    else:
        return 'onethousand' + compose(x % 1000)
```

Comment: This is probably a question better suited to http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not really that we need code, unless you are getting a coding error that we can try to fix. If the question is purely about spelling, shift it to the english stack exchange :)

Comment: Just a thought, shouldnt you have space between "hundred" and "and".

Comment: Thanks for the english.stackexchange, I found an answer there which states that 'and' is used always.

Comment: @AjayNair, I have to count letters, so I intentionally didn't use spaces and hyphens.

Comment: http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/saying_large_numbers01.html was something if found Googling for "spelling large numbers in english" Try that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/rule-for-adding-and-or-hyphens-between-numbers-that-are-spelled-out-fully-in-t

**Three hundred and forty-two**

Leaving out 'and' is more common in US English. Either is acceptable, but including 'and' is more correct.

Hyphenate all compound numbers between twenty-one and ninety-nine.

Comment: I have to disagree with your use of "more correct" just as folks did on the page you linked to. "and" seems more common (perhaps more correct) in the UK. "and" is optional in the US but more commonly left out (as the correct way many elementary schools teach). So it depends on where @gg.kaspersky lives and with whom he/she converses.

Comment: I specified that I need the Britain English version.